# Como autenticar usuário usando sua conta do Google em um app construido com Expo (React Native)?

Tags: react-native, oauth2, expo

Estou desenvolvendo um app com PHP no backend e react native no frontend mobile. O app já tem um frontend web escrito com jquery, e a autenticação é feita usando o Google OAuth. Na versão web está funcionando assim:

O usuário clica em um botão e é autenticado pela função onSignIn:

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var googleToken = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;

    $.post('index.php', {
        url: 'login',
        googleToken: googleToken    
    });
}
```

A variável `googleToken` armazena o valor retornado por `id_token` e é enviada ao servidor, que faz uma requisição a api do Google:

```
file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token='.$googleToken);
```

Sendo um token válido, retorna várias informações como nome, email e avatar, que são usados na autenticação, caso o email já exista, é logado, caso contrário, registrado.

No app mobile, estou desenvolvendo com Expo e gostaria de autenticar da mesma forma, entretanto não estou conseguindo acesso ao `id_token` como na web, mas somente a um token chamado `access_token`, que não possui as informações necessárias(como nome, email e avatar) para autenticar corretamente. Eis um exemplo:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import { makeRedirectUri, ResponseType, useAuthRequest, useAutoDiscovery } from 'expo-auth-session';

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();
const useProxy = Platform.select({ web:false, default:true });

export default function Home() {

  const discovery = useAutoDiscovery('https://accounts.google.com');
  const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
    {
      responseType:  ResponseType.Token,
      usePKCE: false,
      clientId: 'CLIENT_ID',
      redirectUri: makeRedirectUri({
        native: 'com.googleusercontent.apps.GOOGLE_GUID://redirect',
        useProxy
      }),
      scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email']
    },
    discovery
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (response?.type === 'success') {
      const { access_token } = response.params;
    }
  }, [response]);

  return(
    ...
  );
}
```

- Como autenticar usando o Google em um app Expo?
- Como ter acesso ao `id_token` no Expo como na web?
- Ou, como usar o `access_token` para acessar informações do perfil, como
  nome, email e avatar no Expo?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode instalar uma dependência chamada "expo-google-app-auth"

```
expo install expo-google-app-auth
```

Depois de instalar, você consegue extrair o access_token da seguinte forma:

```
import * as Google from 'expo-google-app-auth';
const { type, accessToken, user } = await Google.logInAsync({
  iosClientId: `<YOUR_IOS_CLIENT_ID_FOR_EXPO>`,
  androidClientId: `<YOUR_ANDROID_CLIENT_ID_FOR_EXPO>`,
  iosStandaloneAppClientId: `<YOUR_IOS_CLIENT_ID>`,
  androidStandaloneAppClientId: `<YOUR_ANDROID_CLIENT_ID>`,
});

if (type === 'success') {
  let userInfoResponse = await fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me', {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` },
  });
}
```

Mais informações:

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google/

Comment: O meu problema não é conseguir o `access_token`, e sim como utilizá-lo para conseguir as informações do perfil do usuário, como nome, email e avatar, porque quando faço uma chamada a api do Google com ele, só me é retornado algumas poucas informações inúteis, que literalmente não servem para nada. Na web, fazer a autenticação é muito fácil usando uma propriedade chamada `id_token`, por isso perguntei se é possível recuperá-la também no mobile. O que quero é autenticar o usuário com nome, email e avatar, descobrindo como fazê-lo com o `access_token` ou como recuperar o `id_token` como na web.

Comment: Sobre a api `expo-google-app-auth`, ela foi descontinuada e não funciona, é incompatível com a web, o que já inviabiliza o seu uso, e no android a api do Google retorna erro 400, foi substituida pela `expo-auth-session`.

Answer (score -1):

Olha amigo, o Expo é bem limitado no quesito de produção, te recomendo usar o React Native CLI para projetos complexos como esse teu. Talvez a equipe de expo ainda não tenha um módulo ou uma solução pro teu problema, mas espera outras respostas. Utilize o expo apenas para apps simples ou iniciais.

Comment: Antes de começar o projeto eu dei uma estudada em todas as documentações e não encontrei nenhuma limitação que poderia inviabilizar o desenvolvimento, por isso comecei com o Expo porque facilita em muitas coisas, principalmente porque ainda não sei como ultilizar o React Native na web sem ele. O meu problema é simplesmente dar um jeito de recuperar nome, email e avatar da api OAuth para autenticar, na web é muito fácil por isso não imaginei que ia ter tanta dor de cabeça, já estou a muitos dias revirando documentações em busca de uma solução.